# OpenLayers v 5.3.0 : Map Export

Tags: openlayers

OpenLayers Examples : Map Export

https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/export-map.html

I copy the code but it's not working. Message :
SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level of a module
I found some answers relative to this error but I was not able to solve the problem... I

Answer (score 0):

The answer was in the documentation...
I haven't figured it out yet, but I'm on the right track.